# Node.js / Server.js socket implementation problems

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, stack, stack-overflow

### Having a hard time implementing a node.js/server.js setup

I'm a bit stuck right now, and hoping someone can shed some light. I'm relatively new to sockets in general, but have been programming in javascript on and off for several years, although only about as deep as is necessary to accomplish the task at hand. As a result, my understanding of some of the concepts surrounding the javascript stack heap, and sockets in general are somewhat limited. 
Ok Here's the situation:

I've created an application intended to simply increment a counter, on several machines. Several users can click the "next" button and it will update instantly on all machines.
When you first connect, it retrieves the current number, and spits it out locally.

I've created the server here:

```
var io = require("socket.io");
var sockets = io.listen(8000);
var currentlyServing=0;
sockets.on("connection", function (socket)
{ 
    console.log("client connected");
    socket.emit("receive", currentlyServing);
    socket.on("update", function(serving)
    {
        currentlyServing=serving;
        if(currentlyServing>100)
            currentlyServing=0;
        if(currentlyServing<0)
            currentlyServing=99;
        socket.broadcast.emit("receive", currentlyServing);
        console.log("update received: "+currentlyServing);
    });
});
console.log("Server Started");
```

Here is the relevant (I hope) excerpt from the client side:

```
var socket = io.connect("http://www.sampledomain.com:8000");

//function to update the page when a new update is received
socket.on("receive", function(receivedServing)
{
    document.getElementById('msgs').value=""+String("00" + receivedServing).slice(-2);
    document.getElementById('nowServing').value=receivedServing;
});

//this is called in an onClick event in the HTML source
//sends the new number to all other stations except this one (handled by server side)
function nextServing() 
{
    var sendServing = parseInt(document.getElementById('nowServing').value)+1;
    socket.emit("update", sendServing);
    document.getElementById('nowServing').value=sendServing;
    document.getElementById('msgs').value=""+String("00" + sendServing).slice(-2);
}
```

Ok so here's my problem. This runs absolutely fine in every system I've put it in, smoothly and beautifully - except for IE8. If left alone for more than 2-3 minutes (with no activity at all), I eventually receive a "stack overflow" error. The line number it appears on fluctuates (haven't determined the factors involved yet), but it always happens at that interval. On some workstations it takes longer, which I'm beginning to think has a direct correlation to the amount of phsyical RAM the machine has, or at least how much is being allocated to the web browser.

I found an online function to determine "max stack size", which I realize is not an exact science, however I did consistently get a number in the area of 3000. On my IE11 machine with considerable more resources, I found it to be in the area of 20,000. This may not be relevant, but I figured the more info the better :)

To avoid this problem for now so that the end users don't see this error message, I've take the entire client script, and put it into an iFrame which reloads itself every 60 seconds,essentially resetting the stack, which feels so dirty sitting so close to a web socket, but has bought me the time to post here. I've googled until I can't google any more, but when you search "node.js" or "socket.io" along with "stack overflow" on google, you just get a lot of posts about the two topics that are hosted on the stackoverflow dot com website. ARG lol

Anyone?

EDIT ON NOVEMBER 18TH 2014 AS PER COMMENTS BELOW:

the error message is most often claiming stack overflow at line 1056. IE Developer tools points towards the file socket.io.js. Line 1056 is:

```
return fn.apply(obj, args.concat(slice.call(arguments)));
```

which is insdie this section of the file:

```
var slice = [].slice;

/**
 * Bind `obj` to `fn`.
 *
 * @param {Object} obj
 * @param {Function|String} fn or string
 * @return {Function}
 * @api public
 */


module.exports = function(obj, fn){
  if ('string' == typeof fn) fn = obj[fn];
  if ('function' != typeof fn) throw new Error('bind() requires a function');
  var args = slice.call(arguments, 2);
  return function(){
    return fn.apply(obj, args.concat(slice.call(arguments)));
  }
};
```

Comment: Which version of socket.io are you using? The latest? I found some issues on the github issues page that may be relevant [here](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/issues/385) and [here](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/issues/458) hope that might help.

Comment: It looks like I'm using 1.1.0 - I got that from the History.md file. Thinking I can't remove flash from all of my clients machines (re: first link), and the code mentioned in the second link seems to have been changed in the subsequent versions. Got my hopes up there lol

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint in 'nextServing()'? I would check this first to ensure there is no infinite loop. Does the error always throw within your code or is it within the socket.io code itself?

Comment: The IE 8 stack overflow error is notoriously hard to debug.  I don't see a problem in posted code, so I would advise disable the code part by part until you can narrow it down to a few lines.

Comment: Hey guys, from my reading I'm under the understanding it has something to do with some built in recursive functions. The line has changed once in a while, but almost always it is on line 1056 of socket.io.js thinking I probably should have included this above, but I didn't have the exact line at the time, and have band-aided the problem with a 1 minute refresh to clear the stack, so haven't seen the error in a while...I'll edit the question to include the relevant code right now

Comment: The next thing you should do is look at the "Callstack" view when IE breaks on the error. The error is not where the recursion is occurring it will be further up the call stack. Do you see a common method being called over and over? Even if the actual error location changes there should be a common call further up the call stack.

Comment: A few comments: `parseInt` needs a radix (`parseInt` will interpret leading 0's as octal, you need to `parseInt(val, 10)`). Why isn't this code atomic ? (I mean, if two people have 10, both click next, the server will drop one "+1" and set to 11 twice - you should send an "increment" operation instead of the new value). Can you post as large as possible a sample of your stack at overflow ? Some fields will trigger a change when you click (checkboxes for example), I suspect your code posted here does not include the cause.

Comment: Hi Eric, I'll definitely change the parseInt, thanks for the tip! The reason I'm not sending an "increment" operation and letting the server do it, is that there are actually three separate possible scenarios, an increment, a decrement (is that a word?), and the value is actually an input field that they can manually change as well, so any number could be sent. It seemed to make sense to have the three scenarios use the same function, rather than having three separate functions on the server side.

Comment: Allen-smithee, thanks for your comments as well. I'll check into the "Callstack" view when I get a chance. The Band-Aid solution has been working for now and I've become swamped, but looking forward to another crack at this soon

Comment: I did a small test using your socket.io but in IE 10 and emulated IE8 so that I could debug well.

Started capturing Network in the tab and noticed the requests logging every few seconds.Left alone for few minutes and I see a lot of requests logged in. You will not see this in Chrome because it has true WebSockets.

While IE8 does not support WebSockets `socket.io` emulate that using plain HTTP GET/POST using some mechanism.

So my theory is that even if socket.io works with IE8 it does not reliably emulate web sockets.

Comment: I do not know if socket.io uses flash, but you can set to use long polling on browser that does not support websockets, this should avoid the use of flash.

Answer (score 1):

Find existing issue [Causes a "Stack Overflow" in IE8 when using xhr-polling #385](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/issues/385).

This was fixed by disabling Flash.

Also find [Safari over windows client use xhr-polling instead of websocket - performance are severely harm #1147](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/issues/1147). While this is Safari it may apply to IE8 because it is using similar mechanism.

> I did a small test using your socket.io but in IE 10 and emulated IE8
>   so that I could debug well. Started capturing Network in the tab and
>   noticed the requests logging every few seconds.Left alone for few
>   minutes and I see a lot of requests logged in. You will not see this
>   in Chrome because it has true WebSockets. While IE8 does not support
>   WebSockets socket.io emulate that using plain HTTP GET/POST using some
>   mechanism. So my theory is that even if socket.io works with IE8 it
>   does not reliably emulate web sockets

My advice is to rule out IE 8 for long running client application. [IE8 is no longer supported by Microsoft](http://support2.microsoft.com/gp/microsoft-internet-explorer).

Comment: I did read this as an option as well - however unfortunately upgrading from IE8 is not an option as my clients are using some web-based software from another company that requires IE8 to run. Don't get me started on that topic, lol. The bottom line is we have to make everything we do backwards compatible as far back as IE8. Also cannot disable flash as it is required for these other applications. Will be trying these other solutions this afternoon - running out of time on my bounty

Answer (score 1):

From what I've read it seems that the problem on IE8 might be related to flash. It IE8 uses flashsocket as the default configuration. I suggest to try the following on the client side:

```
 if(navigator.appName.indexOf("Internet Explorer")!=-1 && navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 8")==-1 ){      
      socket = io.connect("http://www.sampledomain.com:8000", {
           transports: ['xhr-polling']
      });
 }
 else
 {
       socket = io.connect("http://www.sampledomain.com:8000" );
 }
```

This should make IE8 use long polling while all other machines use the best method they can.

On a side note: You might also want to consider incrementing the "serving" variable on the server.

Comment: did you mean to say !=-1 for MSIE 8?

Comment: Also just discovered this is an IE 8 browser in IE8 browser mode but IE7 standards document mode, think that changes anything?

Comment: Tried ("MSIE 8")==-1, ("MSIE 8")!=-1, and ("MSIE 7")!=-1 unfortunately no luck still getting the stack overflow error :(

Answer (score -3):

maybe try to replace

```
""+String("00" + receivedServing).slice(-2)
```

with

```
('00' + receivedServing).slice(-2)
```

Comment: No, `String()` should **not** be called with `new`! `new String("abc")` results in `{"0": "a", "1": " b", "2": "c"}`.